# DB2 forces BITWISE-OR if ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE used

Tags: jdbc, db2, resultset, bitwise-operators

I use JDBC to connect to a db2 luw with blu accelaration 11.x db2 luw without blu acceleration has the same issue.

```
conn.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

A possible query in our application is (simplified) where myNumericColumn is a numeric datatype:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE
    myNumericColumn = 123 OR 'ALL' IN (123)
```

`123` can be changed to another value. A prepared string is possible like `'ALL'`. In this case the query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE
    myNumericColumn = 'ALL' OR 'ALL' IN ('ALL')
```

The right hand will be true, so the left hand will not be evaluated. If I remove the right hand (or change the condition to evaluate to false) we got a numeric overflow exception (compare numeric with string).

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Overflow occurred during numeric data type conversion.. SQLCODE=-413, SQLSTATE=22003, DRIVER=4.23.42
```

If I change the createStatement to the following command or remove all ResultSet-attributes (`ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` will be used as default) there is no exception.

```
conn.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)
```

Why forces the JDBC / JDBC-driver / database to use a bitwise or if I change the type of ResultSet? How can this behaviour be changed?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: A minimal verifiable complete example would help investigation..

Comment: Hi mao, thanks for your response. What informations are you looking for?

Comment: Is the underlying table column-organized? Are you using shadow tables?

Comment: Hi mustaccio, at DB2 blu it is column-organized. Tested at db2 without blu - this is row-organized. For the test case there are not any shadow tables used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: **do not do such things**.
There is a statement in the [predicates](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008495.html) description:

- All values specified in a predicate must be compatible

There is no any guarantee, if a predicate of a search condition is really evaluated and in which order in some particular case.